# Realtime application connecting to GlassFish or JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, glassfish

How can I connect a realtime application which has a totally different life-cycle with WebApp to JBoss or GlassFish?

I need it to create a realtime reporting system. Using Sockets is not possible.

Is it possible to attach an application rather than a web applications to Java application servers so they can work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Java EE defines application clients, that can be any java apps.
With some full Java EE profiles, connections via CORBA should be possible and you could then also use C++ clients.

Another option to hook up any client could be messaging.

Comment: Glassfish v3 supports clients.